# How do I download the blockchain from a specific height (409668)

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'd like to download the blockchain from height 409668 (first block on May 1st). I need data on time it was mined, and the amount of transactions it included.

If I don't need to download the blockchain to get this data, that would be 10x better. Where can I get a CSV of this? Otherwise, where can I download the blockchain and get this data from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks?q=id(409668..) will list all the blocks from that height onwards. You can use the filtering at the bottom of the page to restrict the data to the fields you desire. You can then export it to csv.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it for you: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/409668

Hope it helps.